# onSaveInstanceState and Fragments?

Tags: android

How can I get a fragment to save it's state? I've tried everything but no luck, nothing is working.

Ive tried adding:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   myWebView.saveState(outState);
   Log.w("///////", "onSaveInstanceState");

}
```

But this never gets called.

Any ideas?

---

I'm now trying to restore the state of the web view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, container, false);
     myWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webviewtest);
     myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
     myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
     myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
     myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
     myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
     myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");   
     myWebView.setId(1);
     myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
     Log.w("///////", "onCreateView");

    return mainView;
}
```

But the above doesnt work, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into this: [Fragment's onSaveInstanceState() is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503629/fragments-onsaveinstancestate-never-called)

You need to make sure to call `super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` in your `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Is the `onSaveInstanceState()` method at least being called in your Fragment?

Comment: How do I get the state of the web view back?

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes You need to call the restoreState() method in your Fragment.

Comment: Yes I have that: myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState); It does not work.

Comment: Try moving the WebView code to onActivityCreated().  I haven't done a lot of work with WebView, but I'm assuming you will need to wait for the Activity in order to do anything with the WebView.

Comment: Also, from reading the docs [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState(android.os.Bundle)] it looks like you are supposed to call restoreState() first and no longer restores display data.  It looks like there are separate savePicture() and restorePicture() methods for that. **edit:** sorry the SO link parser is failing badly now, go to the restoreState() method in the docs

Comment: I moved it to onActivityCreated(). No Luck. Restoring state before intialting web view doesnt work either,