# Detaching a Fragment not triggering onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, save, fragment, detach

My Android application has an `ActionBar` that changes which `Fragment` occupies a certain `FrameLayout`. I am trying to use `onSaveInstanceState` to save the state of a Fragment when the tab is changed, so that it can be recovered in `onCreateView`.

The problem is, `onSaveInstanceState` is never called. The `Fragment`'s `onDestroyView` and `onCreateView` methods are called, but the `Bundle` supplied to `onCreateView` remains null.

Can someone please explain to me when `onSaveInstanceState` is actually called, how I can make sure it gets called when switching tabs, or the best practice for saving and restoring the state of a `Fragment` when it is detached and re-attached?

Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_log, container, false);

    // Retrieve saved state
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        System.out.println("log retrieved");
    } else {
        System.out.println("log null");
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    System.out.println("log saved");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // more code
}
```

Activity:

```
/**
 * Detach the current Fragment, because another one is being attached.
 */
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.tab_events))){
        if (frEventLog != null) {
            ft.detach(frEventLog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503629/fragments-onsaveinstancestate-never-called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Fragment#onSaveInstanceState` is only called when the `Activity` hosting the `Fragment` is destroyed AND there is a chance that you can come back to the same activity AND the fragment is still added to the `FragmentManager`. The most common case would be screen rotation.

I think your `Fragment` will also need to do [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) in `onCreate` for example. Not exactly sure about that point though.

You should also see this method being called when you press the home button for example. That will destroy the activity but you can go back to it by using the task list for example.

If you just `detach()` the fragment all you need to do to get it back is to ask the `FragmentManager` for it.

There are two examples you should have a look at:

[`ActionBar` FragmentTabs](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.java) and [`TabHost` FragmentTabs](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.java)

The `TabHost` example uses

```
ft.add(containerId, fragment, tag);
// later
fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

to find the instances of previously added `Fragment`s, works until you `remove()` a `Fragment`

---

Regarding `onCreateView` / `onDestroyView`: That is called once a fragment gets detached because the next time you attach it needs to create a new `View`. Note that `Fragment#onDetached()` is not called when you `detach()` the fragment because it is still attached to the `Activity`. It is only detached from the view-hierarchy.

---

There is another nice example on how to retain fragment state / how to use fragments to retain state in Android Training - [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#config-changes).

That example is missing a critical line though:

```
public static RetainFragment findOrCreateRetainFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
    RetainFragment fragment = (RetainFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new RetainFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG).commit(); // << add this
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was under the impression that using setRetainInstance(true) would be rather memory-intensive as it would mean storing the tabs rather than destroying and re-creating them, but I'll give it a go. Do I have to get hold of my Fragments via the FragmentManager or can I keep a reference to them in a field?

Comment: You don't need a reference at all. FragmentManager has references to them but you can add one if you don't add memory leaks. Memory intensity depends on how much you use in your fragments, that can be close to 0 if you do it right

Comment: I think I've got this sorted now with the help of your first example. My problem was actually that I had some code in the Fragment's onActivityCreated() method which was essentially resetting it, as I didn't realise this method would be run more than once.

Comment: Yep, activities are recreated on configuration changes like rotation and you get called that again. Getting the lifecycle right is tricky :/ `OnCreate` would be a place that should get called only once.