# Memory leak in Fragment

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am using the [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library to monitor memory leaks in my app.  I received this memory leak and not sure how to track down what is causing it.

```
05-09 09:32:14.731  28497-31220/? D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper:0.0.21:21.
    * com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper.fragments.MinesweeperFragment has leaked:
    * GC ROOT com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl$PopupLocationInfoBinderCallbacks.zzahO
    * references com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1.zzajo
    * references com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.mContext
    * references com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper.activities.MinesweeperActivity.mFragments
    * references android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mAdded
    * references java.util.ArrayList.array
    * references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
    * leaks com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper.fragments.MinesweeperFragment instance
    * Reference Key: 2f367393-6dfd-4797-8d85-7ac52c431d07
    * Device: LGE google Nexus 5 hammerhead
    * Android Version: 5.1 API: 22
    * Durations: watch=5015ms, gc=141ms, heap dump=1978ms, analysis=23484ms
```

This is my repo :  https://github.com/lawloretienne/Minesweeper

This seems to be an elusive one. I set up an `Interface` to communicate between a `Fragment` and an `Activity`. I set this `mCoordinator` `Interface` variable up in `onAttach()` then I realized I was not nulling it out in `onDetach()`. I fixed that issue but still am getting a memory leak. Any ideas?

#### Update

I disabled the `Fragment` leak watching, and I still get a notification about the activity leaking with the following leak trace :

```
05-09 17:07:33.074  12934-14824/? D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper:0.0.21:21.
    * com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper.activities.MinesweeperActivity has leaked:
    * GC ROOT com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl$PopupLocationInfoBinderCallbacks.zzahO
    * references com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1.zzajo
    * references com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.mContext
    * leaks com.etiennelawlor.minesweeper.activities.MinesweeperActivity instance
    * Reference Key: f4d06830-0e16-43a2-9750-7e2cb77ae24d
    * Device: LGE google Nexus 5 hammerhead
    * Android Version: 5.1 API: 22
    * Durations: watch=5016ms, gc=164ms, heap dump=3430ms, analysis=39535ms
```

Comment: I'd be curious to know if only the fragments leak, or if the activity leaks as well. What if you disable the fragment leak watching, do you still get a notification about the activity leaking?

Comment: but have you manually tried using mat or any other tool?

Comment: @Elltz i have not tried mat or any other tool.

Comment: It seems that you need to call GoogleApiClient .unregisterConnectionCallbacks and GoogleApiClient .unregisterConnectionFailedListener method, due to add listener with GoogleApiClient.Builder. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addConnectionCallbacks(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks)

Comment: @baroqueworksdev I unregistered the callback and listener and nulled out the GoogleApiClient in `onDestroy()`.  But the activity still has that same memory leak.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a heap dump after that update (where the activity leaks) ?\

Comment: When I click `Share heap dump` in the overflow menu, any app that I try to share it in fails. For example, in GMail it says `Permission denied for attachment`.

Comment: Consider adding logging to see if your `onDestroy()` method is getting called. If it's not, as Dmide suggested below, you should put your unregister calls in `onStop()` or `onPause()`

Comment: I have the same problem. I unregistered the callbacks in onStop function of the activity. But I still have the problem. Please share it if you solved it. Thank you.

Comment: It is confirmed that Google play service's v8.1.0's location listener is leaking the activity or service it is attached to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues/26 so maybe this is similar?

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) indicates that it is safe to call `connect()` even if the state is "connected" or "connecting". It also indicates that you can safely call `disconnect()` no matter what the connection state is. Therefore, I would remove the "if" statements around the calls to `connect()` and `disconnect()`. However, I doubt that that will make this "leak" go away.

It is clear that `GamesClientImpl` is storing a reference to your `Activity` as a `Context`. I imagine this is occuring in the construction of the `GoogleApiClient` that happens when you call `GoogleApiClient.Builder.build()`. It seems like a bug to me that the instance of `GoogleApiClient` is still around after your `Activity` has finished. However, if you are supposed to call `connect()` in `onStart()` and `disconnect()` in `onStop()` that seems to imply that you can reuse the connection (since `onStart()` and `onStop()` can be called repeatedly). For this to work, the `GoogleApiClient` **must** keep the reference to your `Context` even after you've called `disconnect()`.

You could try using the global application context instead of your `Activity` context when creating the `GoogleApiClient`, as the global application context lives forever (until the process is killed). This should make your "leak" go away:

```
// Create the Google Api Client with access to Plus and Games
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
05-27 13:15:04.478  24415-25236/com.package D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.package:0.0.52-dev:202.
* com.package.launcher.LauncherActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.q.a
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.m.d
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.c.a
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.j.b
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.aa.f
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ab.mParent
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView.mParent
* references android.widget.FrameLayout.mContext
* leaks com.package.launcher.LauncherActivity instance
* Reference Key: 9ba3c5ea-2888-4677-9cfa-ebf38444c994
* Device: LGE google Nexus 5 hammerhead
* Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22
* Durations: watch=5128ms, gc=150ms, heap dump=5149ms, analysis=29741ms
```

I was using gms ads library and there was a similar leak. So I fixed the above case by handling it onDestroyView() of my fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    if (mAdView != null) {
        ViewParent parent = mAdView.getParent();
        if (parent != null && parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(mAdView);
        }
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

So here I'm basically removing my PublisherAdView from it's parent on onDestroyView().

Also, note that I had to use Application Context when I created the PublisherAdView otherwise I would get the following leak:

```
05-27 13:59:23.684  10041-11496/com.package D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.package:0.0.52-dev:202.
* com.package.launcher.LauncherActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.q.a
* references com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.m.b
* leaks com.package.launcher.LauncherActivity instance
* Reference Key: 5acaa61a-ea04-430a-b405-b734216e7e80
* Device: LGE google Nexus 5 hammerhead
* Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22
* Durations: watch=7275ms, gc=138ms, heap dump=5260ms, analysis=22447ms
```

Not sure if it's going to solve the question above directly but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on `onDestroy()` callback execution, in some cases [it might not be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the). More solid solution is to put your register/unregister code inside `onResume()`/`onPause()`.

[Same goes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146818/detaching-a-fragment-not-triggering-onsaveinstancestate) (for another reason, of course) for Fragment's `onDetach()`, move your sensible code to `onStop()` or `onPause()`.

Comment: This is not the case. `onDestroy` can be not called because the only reason: Process was killed by low memory killer. I believe that it doesn't matter whether you unsubscribed from Google Play Services before process death.

Comment: I don't imply that this is exatcly the reason behind OP's problem, but these "quirks" of SDK are things to be aware of and maybe it could be related to OP's problem.

Comment: @Dmide You are wrong, the only quirk is SDK documentation which states what is not true, see this https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html. And don't listen to all what SO brings, e.g. this is bullcrap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the following code:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity.getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

The issue were the calls `addConnectionCallbacks(this)` and `addConnectionCallbacks(this)`. The class referenced by `this` was keeping a reference to an activity, and as GoogleApiClient won't let go of the references to the connection callbacks/listener, this was resulting in a memory leak.

My solution was to register/unregister the callbacks as the `googleApiClient` connects/disconnects:

```
public void connect() {
    mGoogleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(this);
    mGoogleApiClient.registerConnectionFailedListener(this);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);
    }
}
```