# Android - Fragment doesn't saveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android, I have a fragment and it goes through onPause, destroyView, destroy, but onSaveInstanceState is never called.

Is is this expected?

How can I save the state?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system calls `onSaveInstanceState` when it is about to remove your fragment from the memory/recreate it for any reason. It won't be called otherwise.

If this is your case and `onSaveInstanceState` is still not called, a code snippet of your fragment might help.

This happens many times due to omitting the line of calling this method of the superclass. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503629/fragments-onsaveinstancestate-never-called), for example. Make sure you call it.

Comment: super is definitely being called.  I think maybe the problem is that the fragment manager is never reusing that fragment because the containing view is removed