# Android - add date from one fragment to another running fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have 2 Fragments, A and B

A is already running and has edittexts and data filled out.

There is a button in A that opens fragment B

fragment B is a list of pictures

I need to select a picture from B and send it back to A where it is set as an imageview.

how do I do this with out loosing all the data already filled out in A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Fragment.setTargetFragment and Fragment.getTargetFragment

Answer (score 0):

Use onSaveInstanceState
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Check out this thread if you're still having problems saving the states in fragments.
[Fragment's onSaveInstanceState() is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503629/fragments-onsaveinstancestate-never-called)