# Android - Fragment using NavigationDrawer and onSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, navigation-drawer

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to create a navigation drawer.
Inside one of my fragments, I have an EditText.
I want that the text on the EditText doesn't change if I rotate the screen.

I've tried to use `Bundle savedInstanceState` but it doesn't work.
I reed that I should remove the line `android:configChanges` from my Manifest, but I don't have that line.

I've tried with the correct answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503629/fragments-onsaveinstancestate-never-called), but it's still not working for me.
So what should I do? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the android:configChanges line, then Android will handle the screen rotation. Your app will get destroyed and recreated. Before the app is destroyed, Android calls onSavedInstanceState where you have a chance to save data for the recreation. When the app is recreated, the bundle passed to onCreate is not null and contains your saved state.

Try

```
public void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    bundle.put("editTextString",et.getText().toString());
    super.onSavedInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

and in

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
         String savedText = savedInstanceState.get("editTextString");
         et.setText(savedText);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I try as you say, I get a "The method onSavedInstanceState(Bundle) is undefined for the type Fragment" error. If I change to super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle); it still doesn't work, and I've already tried it before :(