# FragmentManager.getFragment() NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library, savestate

I am using support library v4 and failing to save fragment's state.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    ...
    if(mFragment != null)
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "frag", mFragment);
    ...
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        //Here I get NullPointerException
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "frag");
    }
    ...
}
```

When I call getFragment() NullPointerException is thrown (savedInstanceState contains entry with "frag").

Here is the part of logcat output:

```
04-18 00:10:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(14644): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 00:10:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(14644):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:569)
```

Also I have tried to call `getFragments()` which returns `null`. That appears to me strange.

I will appreciate any help!

---

**Solution:**

I forgot to use `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` inside `onCreate` method.

Comment: Do you call onSaveInstanceState method inside your parent activity? ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752360/2668136))

Comment: Yeah, very stupid of me, forgot to call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)`.Thank You very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Fllo. The problem was that I forgot to call `onSaveInstanceState()` of parent activity.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    //Added this and the problem was solved
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ...
}
```