# ListFragment setRetainInstance (true); does not work

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I use ListFragment

setRetainInstance (true); does not work, I do not know why

savedInstanceState == null

my sources

```
  public class Fragment_Left extends ListFragment {

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onAttach");
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onCreate");
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            setRetainInstance(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        }



         public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState()");


            }


}
```

---

```
    public class Fragment_Left extends ListFragment {
        private ArrayList<Menu_item> menu_list;  .....

     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            setRetainInstance(true);   
menu_list = new ArrayList<Menu_item>();......
```

but After I turned Screen menu_list is null, or I did something wrong?

Comment: "does not work" is a completely useless description of your symptoms. "savedInstanceState == null" -- that has nothing to do with `saveInstanceState(true)`.

Comment: When I use setRetainInstance(true); onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) - savedInstanceState - not null .. or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my first comment. `savedInstanceState` is not strictly tied to `setRetainInstance(true)`. `setRetainInstance(true)` means that your actual `Fragment` object is retained across configuration changes, so your data members remain intact.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9416765/1568164  maybe answer here .. but I can not understand

Comment: okay, tell me how do I store an array in a fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do I store an array in a fragment?

I am assuming that by "store an array in a fragment" that you mean "retain an array used by a fragment across configuration changes". If so:

Option #1: Put it in a data member of the fragment, and call `setRetainInstance(true)` on that fragment.

Option #2: If the array is of a data type that is supported by `Bundle`, override `onSaveInstanceState()`, put the data in the `Bundle`, and retrieve that data in other methods in the new fragment instance created after the configuration change (e.g., `onCreateView()`).

Option #3: If the array really represents the data model of your app, hold it in a central persistent spot that the old and new fragment instances can access, such as a database or a file.