# getting detail fragment content after being replaced

Tags: android, fragment

Suppose I have a master detail/flow screen. I click on and item in items Fragment and `onClickListener` created a new instance of detail fragment (by replacing current fragment with a new one). Detail fragment contains some elements like `checkBox, Spinner`, ...
  I want when I return to my previous detail fragment, the content of the detail fragment be restored. I can't use `onsavedinstanceState` because there is no orientation changed or... so always bundle is null.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Refer to this question

[android fragment- How to save states of views in a fragment when another fragment is pushed on top of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787071/android-fragment-how-to-save-states-of-views-in-a-fragment-when-another-fragmen)

Comment: I read that answer previously. It doesn't restore the content of the detail fragment. Actually I have to define many parameters (like weather each item is checked or not or what is the spinner item in all rows or ...)in `onSavedInstanceState` and restore them back in `onActivityCreated` which is so hard an useless.