# ActionBarSherlock Fragments and Tabs

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm new at Android Development, but I want to start with it. I've currently a problem, I searched for hours, but I couldn't find a solution.

Currently I used this tutorial:
http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example

I implemented it with ActionBarSherlock, it worked like expected, but I want that after switching the tabs and then when switching back to a Tab what was already initialized, that it doesn't get reinitialized, they should open the same View as it was.

How I realize this?
If there is an example to show how it is realized it would be a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each Tab of the application is a Fragment, to switch back to a tab to its state after initialisation, you must 'restore' the state of the fragment once you come back to it.

This stackoverflow question highlights how you can restore the state of the Fragment: [android fragment- How to save states of views in a fragment when another fragment is pushed on top of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787071/android-fragment-how-to-save-states-of-views-in-a-fragment-when-another-fragmen)

Of course, all this is documented in the Fragment guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Do let me know if you have more questions

Comment: So If I inderstand correctly if I want to implement a Tab Navigation with ActionBarSherlock, then while switching trough Activities I always need to restore the View Controller?! Because I always load Data (URLRequest) on each Fragment. Or is there a better solution without Fragments?

Comment: Reading again trought the Fragment Guide I thought it's the besto to use it with a ViewPager and TabsAdapter, which automatically Save the Tabs and Releases if necessary.

Comment: Yup, you can also use FragmentPagerAdapter.