# Fragment Back Navigation Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-activity, fragment

Here I little confuse with Fragments,

I create a one Activity-'A'.
Add Fragment-'X' in Activity.
Replace Fragment-'Y' in place of Fragment-'X'
Now i want to open Fragment-'X' with saved state in Activity-'A'.

Please help me,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use  in `onBackPressed()`

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack();
```

and for more details check [link!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments/12928498#12928498)

Answer (score 1):

```
    To open fragment x from fragment y use the code....
```

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Comment: But it can open in saved state of fragment ?

Comment: i already do that, but it can not open in saved state, it open from initial state. new created state.

Comment: please see this link if this helps .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787071/android-fragment-how-to-save-states-of-views-in-a-fragment-when-another-fragmen