# Android Tab data not showing on back navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

My usecase is as follows:

I have to fetch some data from the web endpoint, and I have to add tabs to the `TabHost`. Every tab has a `listview`, which will further get populated with data from a different web service. So far, I have able to add tabs dynamically in the TabHost, and listview is also populated properly. Everything works fine on first run. Now, when I tap on an item from the listview, its detailed view is opened. Now, if I press back button, I come at the screen with tab view. At this point, the listview under the tab gets disappeared.

I am not getting why this is happening. I am using fragment along with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in my code.

My code is as follows:

**TagsLandingFragment** This fragment will show TabView

Here I am fetching data from the webservice in `onViewCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),
                mFragmentsList);

    getTaggedListings(); //In this method I am fetching data from the server. Once I get the data, I call initialiseTabHost to display the tabs
}

private void initialiseTabHost(JSONArray activeTags, String currentTag) {
    if(!mFragmentsList.isEmpty())
        mFragmentsList.clear();
    if (activeTags.length() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < activeTags.length(); i++) {
            try {
                TagListingsModel model = new TagListingsModel();
                model.setmFragment(TagDataFragment.newInstance(activeTags
                        .getString(i)));

                model.setTagName(activeTags.getString(i));

                if (activeTags.getString(i).equalsIgnoreCase(currentTag)) {
                    model.setActive(true);
                } else {
                    model.setActive(false);
                }

                mFragmentsList.add(model);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    mTabHost.setup();

    int currentTab = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentsList.size(); i++) {

        if (mFragmentsList.get(i).isActive()) {
            currentTab = i;
        }
        addTab(getActivity(), this.mTabHost,
                this.mTabHost
                        .newTabSpec(mFragmentsList.get(i).getTagName()));
        mTabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(
                R.drawable.selector_tab);
    }

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    tabsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Fragments and ViewPager Initialization
    mViewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    mTabHost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**TagDataFragment** is common fragment whose instances are displayed under the tab.

**Update 1**

In `onViewCreated`, I passed `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager` to the tab pager adapter as follows:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),
                mFragmentsList);
}
```

The list now appears but, now the same item is appearing multiple times in listview.

Comment: @Downvoter Please, mention the reason to downvote as well.

Comment: See this link : http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6787071/android-fragment-how-to-save-states-of-views-in-a-fragment-when-another-fragmen