# Continue updating ProgressBar when ViewPager Fragment is off screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments loaded with a ViewPager.

One of the fragments has a ProgressBar being updated like so:

```
cdt = new CountDownTimer(intDuration, 1000) { //(intDuration) milli seconds is total time, 1000 milli seconds is time interval

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        pb.setProgress(pb.getProgress() + 1);
    }
    public void onFinish() { }
}.start();
```

This works great until I swipe to another fragment, then of course the time stops.

How can I get the timer to continue to run while the fragment is not in focus, so that the ProgressBar is in the correct position when returning to the fragment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787071/android-fragment-how-to-save-states-of-views-in-a-fragment-when-another-fragmen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

This retains your fragment even if they're not on screen.